# Backbone select change event not firing

Tags: backbone.js

I have a view which defines a change event on some select controls, but they don't seem to be firing.  The view is something like this:

```
var FiltersView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: FiltersTmpl,
    events: {
        'change #panel_filters select': 'enableSearch'
    },
    enableSearch: function() {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

When I change the dropdown, `enableSearch` doesn't fire.  However, using Chrome Dev Tools, I can use jQuery to setup an event handler like this `$("#panel_filters select").change(function() { debugger; });` and that does in fact fire.  So I know the selector is correct and the select is triggering a change event.  I know it must be a simple syntax problem but it seems like the correct syntax to me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it out. `#panel_filters` is actually the element that I injected my view into.  Technically, it's considered outside the view.  And apparently, view events are scoped to the view itself.  Which is handy I suppose, but I didn't know that. Good to know :-)

Comment: In addition, Backbone splits the hash at spaces. http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-20

Comment: I'll look into the code more later to see exactly why it's doing that, but it does seem to support spaces in selectors.  I'm using it now and it works.  I mean, how are you supposed to do descendant selectors without spaces?

Comment: Hmm. Ignore my last comment. That part of the code is handling `space separated event names`.

Comment: This is where is parses the `events` hash: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-121